# Standard way to describe recursive traits

Tags: recursion, rust, traits

I have the following trait:

```
trait Outer {
    type Inner;
    fn manipulate_and_return( &self ) -> Self::Inner;
}
```

and everything works fine until using boxed and dyns, because the trait implementation over a box would be

```
impl Outer for Box<dyn Outer<Inner = Box<dyn Outer< ... >> >> {
    type Inner = Box<dyn Outer<...>>;
    // code here
}
```

So is there a standard way to solve this problem?
I searched for crates but couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: How do you imagine constructing a value of such a type?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it generically:

```
impl<T: Outer> Outer for Box<dyn Outer<Inner = T>> {
    type Inner = Self;
    //           ^^^^ this makes the impl recursive
    fn manipulate_and_return( &self ) -> Self::Inner {
        todo!()
    }
}
```